How does English define dependent and independent clauses?
I'm a bit confused
Here's what I used to believe (still do, actually). In English, you put a comma between independent clauses (like in Russian). You don't put a comma between an independent and dependent clause (unlike in Russian)
But then I got spelling checkers and GPT telling me I got it all wrong, and that, in fact, I should put a comma in sentences like this one

It was raining, so I took an umbrella

I believe the confusion comes from how independent and dependent clauses are defined in English
In Russian, "so I took an umbrella" would most certainly be considered a dependent clause because it doesn't make sense on its own (because of that "so")
I figure it may be different in English grammar after all
So how does English define dependent and independent clauses, e.g. in the context of punctuation?

This is why it pays to listen to humans more than (for the moment) AI. I'd love to challenge the robots on why they said so. Several times now I've heard the quote "Use commas when necessary to prevent confusion" (wish I could find the source). There is no potential confusion if this one is deleted.

I started an answer, but https://owl.purdue.edu/owl/general_writing/punctuation/independent_and_dependent_clauses/index.html basically says I'm wrong; "so" is a coordinating conjunction and thus a comma is needed. My instinct says you can still skip it for such a short, clear sentence ("It was raining but I staid dry"), but I'm too lazy to hunt down a source to back me up.

Unlike language, which is what it is by virtue of how its speakers speak it, punctuation is a convention with rules handed down from on high.  Whenever there is a major syntactic break you should feel free to use a comma, though the goal is to write so clearly that punctuation is not necessary to guide the reader.

@AndyBonner staid or stayed?

@MichaelHarvey Good catch.

@TimR I suspect that we're not disagreeing, but I would be in favor of taking my original quote to mean "Don't use a comma when not necessary to prevent confusion." Plenty of commas, if deleted, wouldn't cause actual ambiguity or misreadings, but might force the reader to pause and re-read before figuring out the relationship of words. (Try it in that preceding sentence, for instance.) But sometimes ill-advised learners (or those who should know better!) insert them anywhere there might be a bit of pause in rhetorical delivery: "We are not, that kind, of people. I know, we can do, better."

English doesn't define such things. Grammarians who have theories about how English works may define such things - but they don't necessarily all agree.

I. Comma Rules for dependent and independent clause:
OP has stated:

Here's what I used to believe (still do, actually). In English, you put a comma between independent clauses (like in Russian). You don't put a comma between an independent and dependent clause (unlike in Russian)

OP is right as a general rule, but there are cases when comma is used for a dependent clause.

when a sentence starts with a dependent clause we use a comma.
comma is used for a non-restrictive relative clause..
Also there are some cases when we don't use comma for an independent clause (explained below)

II. Commas - Eight basic uses:.
The website below states the various uses of comma, but I have separated the comma rules for clauses as it is the topic discussed:

1.USE A COMMA TO SEPARATE INDEPENDENT CLAUSES..
Rule: Use a comma before a coordinating conjunction (and, but, yet, so, or nor, for) when it joins
two complete ideas (independent clauses).
1.He walked down the street, and then he turned the corner.
2.You can go shopping with me, or you can go to a movie alone.
.
2. USE A COMMA AFTER AN INTRODUCTORY CLAUSE OR PHRASE..
Rule: Use a comma after an introductory clause or phrase. A comma tells readers that the introductory clause or phrase has come to a close and that the main part of the sentence is about to begin.
1.When Evan was ready to iron, his cat tripped on the cord.
.
3. USE COMMAS TO SET OFF NONRESTRICTIVE CLAUSES..
Rule: Use commas to enclose clauses not essential to the meaning of a sentence. These nonessential clauses are called nonrestrictive.
Both restrictive and nonrestrictive clauses may begin with a relative pronoun (such as who, whom,
whose, that, which).
1.Steven Strom, whose show you like, will host a party next week. (nonrestrictive).
2.John, who spent the last three days fishing, is back on the job again. (nonrestrictive).
3.The gentleman who is standing by the fireplace is a well-known composer. (restrictive).
https://www.okanagan.bc.ca/sites/default/files/2020-03/commas.pdf

III. Comma not used for compound predicate..
A compound predicate occurs when the subject in the sentence is doing more than one action and is shared by two or more verbs. These verbs are joined by a conjunction, or a connecting word, such as 'and,' 'or,' and 'but. '.
Examples:

Arthur Conan Doyle worked as a doctor and wrote novels. (same subject for both verbs - worked and wrote.)
They live in Vienna and speak German. (same subject for both verbs - live and speak)


Explanation: It was raining, so I took an umbrella.- If a clause starts with For, And, Nor, But, Or, Yet, So - it is coordinating conjunctions. We can convert it into subordinating clause and then comma is not required. It was raining hence I took an umbrella. (so doesn't have a good replacement). I took an umbrella because it was raining.

Thank you. Can you comment on this? "Be aware that so can act as either a coordinating conjunction or a subordinating conjunction"

@SergeyZolotarev The statement is not entirely correct. "so" is coordinating conjunction. "so that" is subordinating conjunction. Sometimes "that" is omitted. https://www.quickanddirtytips.com/articles/so-and-so-that-coordinating-or-subordinating-conjunctions/#:~:text=%E2%80%9CSo%20that%E2%80%9D%20is%20a%20subordinating,don%27t%20use%20modal%20verbs

Thanks. Here's a trickier one: why is "so" considered a coordinating, not subordinating conjunction?

@SergeyZolotarev  We cannot start a sentence with a coordinating conjunction. But this rule is broken many times and we can find sentences beginning with And, But. I also had previously looked for an answer to this. Because sometimes the same coordinating clause can be turned into a subordinating clause. So we have to accept it as a rule of grammar.

I remember this only because FANBOYS has always stuck in my head. FANBOYS are coordinating conjunctions: For, And, Nor, But, Or, Yet and So. Because each clause can stand alone, and they are connected by a coordinating conjunction, they are both independent clauses:

It was raining.
I took an umbrella.

I think it's recommended to add a comma between the two, but I wouldn't say it's required if the sentence is concise and the comma isn't necessary to interpret it correctly.
I think the hard rule is that when you are connecting independent and dependent clauses, and the dependent clause comes first, you need a comma.
Reference from Grammarly.com

Thank you. I don't get this. Why do they determine whether a sentence can stand on its own differently? They don't strip e.g. "if" ("'if the interview goes well' doesn't make sense on its own, it's a dependent clause"), but they do strip "so" ("'I took an umbrella' does make sense on its own, that's why 'so I took an umbrella' is an independent clause")

"Be aware that so can act as either a coordinating conjunction or a subordinating conjunction" Now, I'm totally confused
